# PowerShell profile does not load

Tags: powershell

I created the file `C:\Users\<myname>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`; however, PowerShell does not load it on launch. I have tested both the default PowerShell as well as VS Code's integrated PowerShell. I also tried renaming the `profile.ps1` file to `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`, but this changed nothing. I relaunched the applications in question after each change.

**Running `Test-Path $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts` returns True.**

The profile currently only contains one line (`Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function Complete`). After launching PowerShell or VS Code's integrated shell, running `Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler | findstr -i Tab` reveals that it has not been set. Copying and pasting the line from the profile, running it, then running the `Get-...` command again reveals that it is properly set, and the change does what it's supposed to. Relaunching the shell reverts back to the default.

Is there some other step I need to do to get PowerShell to execute the profile? (I come from a Linux/UNIX background and I assume PowerShell works similarly, but of course PowerShell is designed completely differently). If there is no extra step, why does PowerShell not load the profile in this case?

Additional Info:

```
> $profile | Format-List * -force
AllUsersAllHosts       : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    : C:\Users\<myname>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost : C:\Users\<myname>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
Length                 : 76
```

Comment: Are you asking how to modify the default PowerShell profile?

Comment: Are you within a PowerShell console or PowerShell ISE.  This makes a difference, and I am unable to submit my answer, until you provide that information.

Comment: I'm just using PowerShell.exe; `$host.Name` returns 'ConsoleHost'

Comment: Update your question with the sanitized output of `$PROFILE | Format-List * -Force`

Comment: Have you tried modifying `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1`?

Comment: No... but it helped solve it in a weird way. Since I started using PS (months ago) there was always a random warning that would appear (can't remember what it was) and I would always clear the console. Adding a copy of profile.ps1 to that path increased the length of the warnings, which is the only reason I noticed them - turns out one of them was 'running scripts is disabled on this system.' (I set the execution policy and it now works). The weird thing is that I never had a profile file and the original warning is now gone. (All I remember is that it had nothing to do with profiles.)

Comment: See, with Windows I'm so used to dumb errors and warnings that mean nothing that I just got used to seeing them every time. :D

Comment: Sounds like you should self-answer your question, since the answer I wrote up, wouldn't have any information that actually resulted in a solution.

Comment: Yep, I'll do that. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Solution: change execution policy

1. Launch PowerShell as administrator
2. `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

#### The error message as shown:

```
. : File C:\Users\<myname>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ . 'C:\Users\<myname>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

#### The Lesson:

The odd thing is that I saw an error message (which was not important) every time I launched PS before so I just got used to ignoring it. *Creating* the `profile.ps1` file caused the execution policy error to appear, but also caused the previous error to *stop* appearing, so I just skipped over it because, without reading the details, it just looked like the same block of red text. (The previous error now appears to be impossible to replicate, for some reason.)

In the end, the problem can be described as *"User got used to ignoring trivial and unimportant error, so the important error went unnoticed."*

Comment: This does not work for me.  I even logged off and back on and then executed `get-executionpolicy` which returned `Unrestricted`.   Yet still the shell is not running my profile.ps1 file.

Comment: In my personal case `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` also worked and should be more secure than `Unrestricted`.